# Can't return substring in Lua

Tags: lua

This findword function is being called from another function. In below function, s contains a long string.
But problem is as soon as I use ':' for s:byte and and s:sub , it says s is a leaf node without children.Where I am doing it wrong

2.Is there any function called _isWhite in lua? If not, what should I substitute it with ?

```
local function findword(s,i)
local j=i+1
while not _iswhite(s:byte(j)) and j<#s do
j=j+1
end
return s:sub(i,j),j
end
```

Comment: It is likely the variable you are passing in is not a string. Perhaps a string can be retrieved by getting the node's value or by using the `s=tostring(s)` to convert s to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To process all words in a string try this:

```
for w in s:gmatch("(%S+)") do print(w) end
```

Following the code you posted, a word is just a sequence of non-whitespace characters.

If you want the position where each word ends, try this:

```
for w,k in s:gmatch("(%S+)()") do print(w,k-1) end
```

Comment: +1 nice, but if @gwell is correct (seems likely), then it would have to be something _like_ `for w in tostring(s):gmatch... end`.

Comment: No, but my requirement is to return the word on every iteration with the index of last character of that word which cant't be achieved by what is suggested above. Any suggestions for that ?

Comment: @ihf: Could you please give me some idea how putting () after (%S+) returned index number, please ?

Comment: @Simrankaur, these are empty captures, see the last paragraph of http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1.